# Assigning random value to a variable in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, random

I have a random value which is being pulled from object method as below:

```
salesOrderPage.setOrderNumber(miscPxUtil.getDateString()+ random.nextInt());
```

Now I need to make use of the same value for other operation which I assigned to a variable like below:

```
String Unique = salesOrderPage.setOrderNumber(miscPxUtil.getDateString()+ random.nextInt());
```

Which gives an error as `Cannot convert from void to string`.  Please help me out as I am a beginer in selenium webdriver coding

Comment: sounds like you are beginner to programming, too `:)`

Comment: It seems like you are using the setter where you should have been using the getter. Check the `salesOrderPage` object to see if it has a `getOrderNumber()` method. So the first use of the method to set the value is correct, but when you need to pass it to `Unique` use the `getOrderNumber()` method instead. P.S. don't capitalize your variable names.

Comment: Selenium doesn't assign random values to variables. That's programming. Selenium has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

salesOrderPage.setOrderNumber doesn't return a value.  You're trying to set String Unique to the result of that method call.

Why don't you generate the string first and then pass the value into the set method?